# Jquery mobile datebox in Android Browser issue

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, datebox

I am trying to open a jquery mobile datebox in a jquery dialog. I have assigned a z-index to the dialog which is 400. And the datebox appears to be 500. It works pefect on the PC browsers, and I test it with iphone safari, it is also good. But in the android browser, after the datebox opens, at the first time it is on the top, then it goes under the dialog. Does anyone know what is the problem here, thank you very much.